# Data Migration From Mysql to postgresql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, talend, data-migration

Stack Overflow Team,
My Requirement is need to transfer data from mysql to postgresql.
Currently I'm using talend for syncing the data.
But the problem is that there is also deletion of data occuring randomly from mysql after sometime on the basis of my bussiness logic.
and i want to delete the same row from postgre as well
can you suggest which tool is better for my requirement and that will be unpaid also

MYSQL ----->>>> POSTGRESQL

Comment: "can you suggest which tool is better for my requirement and that will be unpaid also" Questions asking us to recommend or find tool, software library or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: i want to know any tool, script or library which through i can sync data so that count will remain same in both db mysql and postgresql as well

Answer (score 0):

DataX, an open source tool that supports synchronize data in deferent database.You could  excuted sql statment befor or after synchronized data.

https://github.com/alibaba/DataX/blob/master/introduction.md